# How to get MAPI Note Color in Outlook ost or pst files?

Tags: outlook, mapi

Need to mention that I'm using a 3rd party pst + ost reader and parser, so not using MS objects, just a how to query.
Just wanna know how new Outlook 2021 works to store the MapiNoteColor?
Long time ago it was PidLidNoteColor with only 5 colors as mentioned here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxonote/57c943ca-852c-4dca-b291-deecf24454af

But now, using the latest Outlook 2021 in combination with exchange hosted @outlook.com email account, making the new notes is not limited to those 5 values, you can assign a category color.
And in many cases PidLidNoteColor is wrong!
Anyone has any info on this?

Tried to get the MapiNoteColor from PidLidNoteColor but received wrong results in most cases!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, category color and note color are two different things, but in case of Notes, category color takes precedence over note color (which is a really old property).

Comment: Hi, thanks, yeah I know, but category colors (real color values) do not seem to be saved in the msg files, or I'm wrong?

Comment: Hi, thanks, yeah I know, but category colors (real color values) do not seem to be saved in the msg files, or I'm wrong?

Comment: That is correct - OlCategoryColor in OOM is just an enum, Outlook is free to render the color any way it sees fit in its current color scheme. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olcategorycolor

Comment: Note that messages only contain the category value. The category definition is stored in the `IPM.Configuration.CategoryList` hidden message in the default Calendar folder.

Comment: BTW, you can see how the category is stored in Outlook Spy (https://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm , I am its author) - click IMessage button to see the property values. To see category definitions, go to the Calendar folder, click IMAPIFolder button, go to the "Associated Contents" tab, double click on the IPM.Configuration.CategoryList message.